# Map framebuffer into an X window

Tags: linux, framebuffer, xorg

Is there any easy hack or existing application that shows an existing framebuffer device (eg. like `/dev/fb0` in an X window? So it would be possible to monitor multiple framebuffer applications simultaneously or peek on them from time to time without leaving the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't x11vnc supposed to be able to do that?

```
x11vnc -rawfb map:/dev/fb0@1024x768x32
```

Comment: Sounds cool, hoever can't get it working properly. If connecting with a VNC client, the picture looks garbled like raw data wrapped to a wrong image width. However, the mess seems to consist of colors actually used on my screen, so it's not totally wrong... I tried several width settings, including the correct one, however it never shows an intact image. Maybe an issue with my VGA card, I will investigate this by saving the fb to a file and check the image contained.

Comment: @dronus I'm facing the same situation. How you figured out a fix for this?